# How to insert values to placeholder asp.net (vb)?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I'm trying to do a page that creates hyperlink dynamically and puts it in the placeholder. However, whenever I create two hyperlinks, the first created hyperlink is just replaced by the previously created hyperlink. Is there a way that created hyperlinks will just add up in the placeholder, not replacing previously created hyperlinks?

What code should I add for that to happen?

This is my code.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim link As New HyperLink()
    Dim ltr As New Literal()
    link.ID = 1
    link.Text = TextBox1.Text
    link.NavigateUrl = "Default.aspx?field1=" + TextBox2.Text + " "
    ltr.Text = "<br/>"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ltr)
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(link)
```

Thanks in advance.